# Problems with regular expressions on Google Tag Manager

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I am trying to make a Regular Expression on Google Tag Manager, more specific in a trigger. The trick is this: the url that I need to filter have this type of url: `webpage.com/checkout/#/some_parameter`, but I have been trying different options, without success.

The options that I tried are:

`checkout\/[#]` or `checkout\/[^a-z][^A-Z]`, and other expressions without any success. I used the preview mode, but the trigger doesn't activate, no matter what I try.

Anyone have an idea on what is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: You're not escaping the slashes. Try `\/checkout\/(.*?)\/`

Comment: No, didn't work, at least in preview mode. Do you mind to explain your regular expression?

Comment: You can see my example here: https://regex101.com/r/gT3wW5/2

Comment: I see, but there is a trick... There are some pages, like webpage.com/checkout/another_thing/some_parameters.. According to your regular expresion, it will look for any character after the first slash, so it won't help... I think that the regular expression is faling due to the #

Comment: Nope. It still works. https://regex101.com/r/gT3wW5/4

Comment: Let me try to explain again. The filter that i want to do is only for:
webpage.com/checkout/#/some_parameter, but i don't want to include in the filter this type of page: webpage.com/checkout/another_thing/some_parameters. So, the filter is only for the url with the hashtag, not for the other type of page. I don't know if GTM have any type of problem with the #, that seems is generated for JavaScript dynamically

Comment: Then what's wrong with `\/checkout\/#\/` ?

Comment: I don't know... I tried that option before, and i tried right now, and the preview mode shows that the tag wasn't triggered

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for the value after the hashtag I suggest you dispense with the regex. Instead you create an URL type variable and set "component type" to "fragment". This will return the value after the hashmark. You can now use that in your rules, e.g. set an exception trigger if the fragment value is some_parameters.

If the presence of any hash mark serves as exception you should be able to set a condition "PAGE URL does not contain #", again without using regex.